# Multipart upload using Quickblox for large files

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, quickblox

I am using Quickblox as a backend service and so far everything has been great, but I am having some trouble uploading large video files.

Here's how I normally upload video files using the Quickblox iOS SDK:

```
[QBRequest TUploadFile:self.videoData fileName:@"testing" contentType:@"video/quicktime" isPublic:YES successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBCBlob *blob) {
            //Success

        } statusBlock:^(QBRequest *request, QBRequestStatus *status) {

            // Update progress
            NSLog(@"completion : %f", status.percentOfCompletion);

        } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
            //
        }];
```

This works fine most of the time, but when `self.videoData` is bigger, like 20MB, the app will crash. After doing research on StackOverflow, it looks like the right way to upload large files to a server without crashing the app is to do a multipart upload.

How can I do a multipart upload with Quickblox? I'm willing to use the REST API if the iOS SDK will not work.

I just need to know if this is possible or not, and if yes then how to get started.

Comment: Have you checked this? [quickblox.com:Upload file on Amazon](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-bb10)

Comment: @the_UB Good find! I saw that earlier but I can't use it because I don't even know what language it's in. That code is for a Blackberry app, and I need to be able to this for an iOS app. Any idea what language that code is in? Any idea how to recreate that code in Objective-C?